# nextFloat is not working on Random object

Tags: java

why this line of code has error message ?

```
Random ran2 = new Random();
float distance = ran2.nextFloat(50f);
```

Comment: it does not, it compiles and works perfectly fine

Comment: @Pavel [It depends on the Java version used](https://ideone.com/FOpxz0).

Comment: A quick glance at the Javadoc would have solved your own question.

Comment: *Any* time you ask a question with an error (whether that's a compilation error or an exception), please make sure you include the *full* details of the error in the question. "Has error message" isn't *nearly* as useful as showing the error you receive. (It's also often useful to include details of the version of the platform you're using.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The method `nextFloat(float)` is implemented in interface [`java.util.random.RandomGenerator` (`docs.oracle.com`)](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/random/RandomGenerator.html), which was introduced in [Java 17 (`en.wikipedia.org`)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_17).

Compiling this code with a JDK < 17 will result in a compilation error:

```
...
... error: method nextFloat in class Random cannot be applied to given types;
...
```

There are two ways to solve this issue:

- Upgrade to a JDK >= 17 (the recommended approach)
- Copy what `RandomGenerator.nextFloat(float)` does (the actual implementation can be found in [`jdk.internal.util.random.RandomSupport` (`github.com`)](https://github.com/openjdk/jdk/blob/jdk-17+35/src/java.base/share/classes/jdk/internal/util/random/RandomSupport.java#L747)):

  ```
  float distance = ran2.nextFloat();
  distance = distance * 50f;
  if (distance >= 50f) // may need to codistancedistanceect a distanceounding pdistanceoblem
    distance = Float.intBitsToFloat(Float.floatToIntBits(50f) - 1);
  ```